# Linq error "Input string was not in a correct format."

Tags: c#, linq, sql-server-2008

My query looks like this:

```
var rport = from exc in db.Exception_Datas
            join emp in db.Emp_infos on exc.Emp_id equals emp.ID
            where (exc.Action_date >= frm && exc.Action_date <= to) && 
                   emp.Branch == cmbBranch.SelectedValue && 
                   emp.Dept == cmbDept.SelectedValue && 
                   emp.ID == Convert.ToInt32(cmbEmp.SelectedValue)
            select new
            {
                emp.Emp_name,
                emp.ID,
                emp.Designation,
                emp.Dept,
                emp.Branch,
                exc.Action_date
            };
```

I am contracting cmbEmp.Items like this:

```
var allEmp = from emp in db.Emp_infos select emp;
myItem.Text = "--Select--";
myItem.Value = "0";
cmbEmp.Items.Add(myItem);
foreach (var semp in allEmp)
{
    myItem = new RadComboBoxItem();
    myItem.Text = semp.Emp_name.ToString();
    myItem.Value = semp.ID.ToString();
    cmbEmp.Items.Add(myItem);
}
```

I've followed some other question and post in SO and out of SO. But any of them didn't helped me solve the problem. I am getting this error:

> {"Input string was not in a correct format."}  System.SystemException {System.FormatException}

Comment: The issue seems to be with `Convert.ToInt32(cmbEmp.SelectedValue)`, Make sure your `SelectedValue` has an `int` parse able value. Also don't do that in LINQ query, parse it before your query and then use the value in your query.

Comment: Just to elaborate on what @Habib mentioned, you don't want to do the cast as part of your LINQ query is because it will perform the cast for *every* record.

Comment: @habib > I did it as Muhammad Umars answer. But for this I am not getting any value. Can you guess why?

Comment: @Rashad, you are not getting proper selected value. Put a debugger point and see what you get in `cmbEmp.SelectedValue`. The issue is not related to your LINQ query.

Answer (score 3):

Issue seems to be on this line. `Convert.ToInt32(cmbEmp.SelectedValue)`. Make sure it parsed correctly and parsed it before using in linq query. Try like this

```
int empId;

if (Int32.TryParse(cmbEmp.SelectedValue, out empId))
{
    var rport = from exc in db.Exception_Datas
        join emp in db.Emp_infos on exc.Emp_id equals emp.ID
        where (exc.Action_date >= frm && exc.Action_date <= to) && 
               emp.Branch == cmbBranch.SelectedValue && 
               emp.Dept == cmbDept.SelectedValue && 
               emp.ID == empId
        select new
        {
            emp.Emp_name,
            emp.ID,
            emp.Designation,
            emp.Dept,
            emp.Branch,
            exc.Action_date
        };
}
```

Comment: Though your answer solved the crash but there is a problem. I don't get any data. Can you guess why?

Comment: Why don't you tell us what the value of cmbEmp.SelectedValue is?

Comment: @Rashad: You need to find out what the *value* of `cmbEmp.SelectedValue` is *when the exception happens*.